Empty Encoder Map but the Huffman tree is generating
So I am making a data compression tool using Huffman Encoding and decoding, I am at the stage where I have built the Huffman Tree and it is a success but I am feeding that tree in a GenerateCodes function which should return a Map with the char and their prefix codes. Unfortunately is has failed to do so, and me too in finding the issue.
package main

import(
 "bufio"
 "fmt"
 "os"
 "log"
 "io"
 "container/heap"
)

type HuffTree interface {
    Freq() int
}

type LeafNode struct {
    char rune 
    freq int
}

type HuffNode struct {
    freq int
    left_child, right_child HuffTree
}

func (self LeafNode) Freq() int{
    return self.freq
}

func (self HuffNode) Freq() int{
    return self.freq
}

type PriorityQueue []HuffTree

func (pq PriorityQueue) Len() int {return len(pq)}

// This is a min heap: item with lowest priority comes first
// So when we call Pop() on pq we will get the lowest frequency character
func (pq PriorityQueue) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return pq[i].Freq() < pq[j].Freq()
}

func (pq PriorityQueue) Swap(i, j int) {
    pq[i], pq[j] = pq[j], pq[i]
}

func (pq *PriorityQueue) Push(x interface{}) {
    *pq = append(*pq, x.(HuffTree))
}

func (pq *PriorityQueue) Pop() (x interface{}) {
    n := len(*pq)
    x = (*pq)[n-1]
    *pq = (*pq)[:n-1]
    return 
}

func BuildTree(m map[rune]int) HuffTree {
    trees := make(PriorityQueue, 0)
    
    for char, freq := range m {
        trees = append(trees, LeafNode{char, freq})
    }

    heap.Init(&trees)
    
    fmt.Printf("Initial Priority Queue:\n")
    for _, tree := range trees {
        switch t := tree.(type) {
        case LeafNode: 
            fmt.Printf("Leaf:%c Freq: %d\n", t.char, t.freq)
        }
    }

    for trees.Len()>1{
        tree1 := heap.Pop(&trees).(HuffTree)
        tree2 := heap.Pop(&trees).(HuffTree)
        internalNode := &HuffNode{tree1.Freq() + tree2.Freq(), tree1, tree2 }
        heap.Push(&trees, internalNode)
    }

    return heap.Pop(&trees).(HuffTree)
}

func CountOccurrences(file io.Reader) map[rune]int {
    m := make(map[rune]int)

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        for _,char := range(scanner.Text()){
                m[char] += 1
        }
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return m
}

func GenerateCodes(tree HuffTree, prefix []byte, encoder map[rune]string) map[rune]string{
    switch t := tree.(type) {
    case LeafNode:
        encoder[t.char] = string(prefix)
    case HuffNode:
        GenerateCodes(t.left_child, append(prefix, '0'), encoder)
        prefix = prefix[:len(prefix)-1]

        GenerateCodes(t.right_child, append(prefix, '1'), encoder)
        prefix = prefix[:len(prefix)-1]
    }
    return encoder
}

func main(){
    args := os.Args
    if len(args) == 1 {
        fmt.Println("Provide argument")
    }

    f, err := os.Open(args[1])
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer f.Close()

    frequencyMap := CountOccurrences(f)

    fmt.Printf("Frequency Map\n")
    for char, freq := range frequencyMap {
        fmt.Printf("%c: %d\n", char, freq)
    }

    huffManTree := BuildTree(frequencyMap)
    fmt.Printf("Encoder Map\n")
    encoderMap := GenerateCodes(huffManTree, []byte{}, make(map[rune]string))
    for char, prefixCode := range encoderMap {
        fmt.Printf("char: %c, value: %s\n", char, prefixCode)
    }
}



Frequency Map
A: 3
b: 2
c: 1
a: 5
Huffman Tree:
Node (Freq: 11)
----Leaf: a (Freq: 5)
------Node (Freq: 6)
--------Leaf: A (Freq: 3)
----Node (Freq: 3)
------Leaf: c (Freq: 1)
------Leaf: b (Freq: 2)
Encoder Map
Nothing....

internalNode := &HuffNode{tree1.Freq() + tree2.Freq(), tree1, tree2 
heap.Push(&trees, internalNode)

This is an object of type *HuffNode, not HuffNode.
GenerateCodes switches on HuffNode, not *HuffNode and since none of the types match, returns immediately.
But why does &HuffNode satisfy the HuffTree interface? From the Go spec, https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_sets

The method set of a type determines the methods that can be called on an operand of that type.

The method set of a defined type T consists of all methods declared with receiver type T.
The method set of a pointer to a defined type T (where T is neither a pointer nor an interface) is the set of all methods declared with receiver *T or T.



i think it is because of auto dereferencing

Thanks it worked, I changed the code. One more issue in this code is when I am appending the prefix slice in a recursive call I forgot to remove the line after that which resulted in out of bound error.
